# How to find user stories with parent that contains certain value in custom field?

Tags: rally

I have a list of user stories which are assigned to different features (assuming none of them are orphaned).  On the Portfolio Item Feature level, there is a custom boolean field called `Redelivered`.

I want to find out which user stories are associated with a parent feature where `Redelivered = True`, but I can't seem to do that from user story level, such as "parent.c_redelivered = true"

Answer (score 0):

Already solved this myself.
We could use `PortfolioItem.c_Redelivered = True` to accomplish what I wanted.